# 1265: Data truncated for column 'envio' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm with a problem in following insert SQL below:

```
insert into cad_manutencao (id, 
                            causa_provavel, 
                            envio, 
                            retorno, 
                            nota_envio, 
                            rastreamento, 
                            transportadora, 
                            chegou)
values (1,
        'TESTANDO ASSISTENCIA',
        '12/02/2015 15:00:00',
        '12/02/2015 15:00:00',
        'S/NF',
        'Assistência',
        1,
        1)
```

When i run this SQL the MySQL return this warning:

> "1265: Data truncated for column 'envio' at row 1"

This SQL works and the register is added, but the date fields are filled as `NULL`

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are the data types for envio retorno

Comment: These two fields are `date`

Comment: in this fields i tried use '12/02/2015 15:00:00' or '12/02/2015' values, but doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid format for a date in mysql. You have to change the query like this :

```
insert into cad_manutencao (id, 
                        causa_provavel, 
                        envio, 
                        retorno, 
                        nota_envio, 
                        rastreamento, 
                        transportadora, 
                        chegou)
values (1,
    'TESTANDO ASSISTENCIA',
    '2015-02-12 15:00:00',
    '2015-02-12 15:00:00',
    'S/NF',
    'Assistência',
```

Date format for mysql is yyyy-mm-dd.